# How to call controller from ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a graph (based on d3) in a rails app. Users click on the graph and then I'm hoping that the click will result in showing a page in my rails app based on a name passed into the show action or a users controller. The problem is that I keep on getting the response:

`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show`

which is because I am inadverntently passing the parameters

```
{"id"=>"show"}
```

which I dont know how to correct.

The ajax call (with a bit of javascript from d3.js which is where I get the name from) is:

```
    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.group * 3; })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag)
    //   .on('click', connectedNodes)
      .on("click",  function(d) { getprofile(d.name); });

//       function getprofile(name){
//     console.log(name);
// };



      function getprofile(d){
      $.ajax({
        url: "/users/show" ,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { name: JSON.stringify(d.name) }
    })};
```

and the controller is

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController

...
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:name])
end
end
```

I guess I want the parameters to be

```
{"name" => "the_name_of_the_d.name_I_have_passed}
```

My routes are as follows

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern               Controller#Action
graph_index GET    /graph/index(.:format)    graph#index
 graph_data GET    /graph/data(.:format)     graph#data
            GET    /graph/index(.:format)    graph#index
      users GET    /users(.:format)          users#index
            POST   /users(.:format)          users#create
   new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      users#new
  edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) users#edit
       user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      users#show
            PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
            PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      users#update
            DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      users#destroy
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Well, you're explicitly passing in something pretty different. Without knowing what `d` is it's impossible to help, though.

Comment: d.name is an object called when a user clicks a d3.js graph I have created. For the purposes of this its just text

Comment: Why not just `{ name: d.name }`? I mean, just guessing because you don't provide much to go on.

Comment: I've added more information and code as requested. Let me know what else needs to be added

Comment: 1) You're calling `getprofile` with `d.name` already, so trying to get `d.name` inside `getprofile` will always fail. 2) The default route will be using `/users/:id`, right? Rails will load up `:id` with whatever is in that place in the URL. 3) You're making a GET request to `/users`; do you even have a route for `/users/show`? Impossible to say without seeing relevant output from `rake routes`.

Comment: Rake routes have been added as requested. The default route is /users/:id

Comment: So why are you calling `/users/show`? You're passing `show` as the ID. Your parameters are ignored. I'd probably spin through some Rails tutorials for a bit; if you want a new route, add it; if you want to process parameters differently, you'll want to understand how it works by default first.

Comment: I'm still left with the problem that id is passed as the parameter and not name. It's really the parameter that needs to be renamed as otherwise I'm only able to reference one column (the :id) of my user database table. Can you at least offer some direction? As much as its easy to tell someone to go and read a book its not really a helpful direction.

Comment: If you want a custom route then you can create one, check out the [Rails Routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), specifically the [section on non-RESTful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes). You can route things to whichever controller you want and use arbitrary parameters, like a name. For example, `/userByName/:name`. The reason I want to read is so you learn, because this is Rails 101--if you don't understand how and why things are working the way they do it will be *significantly* harder to accomplish anything significant.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

When you are calling for `getprofile()` function you are passing already `d.name`, you should change this into: `getprofile(d)`

---

your controller you are calling `params[:name]`, so in ajax you have to change `data: { name: JSON.stringify(d.name) }`

Comment: I changed as suggested but got the same error of ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show and mainly because it is passing {"id"=>"show"}

Comment: I have corrected my code but now I get the parameters as {"name"=>"\"\"",
 "id"=>"show"}